# Wordpress - Add social buttons on Products Page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add the social icons onto my product page. i.e `https://flowersforeveryone.co.za/product/cheerful-orange-tulips/`
just under the 'Add to Cart' button.

I have a 'social menu' set up. How do I add this please?

My single content-single-product page looks like this, but i don't know where to start -

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_before_single_product.
 *
 * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product' );

if ( post_password_required() ) {
    echo get_the_password_form(); // WPCS: XSS ok.
    return;
}
?>
<div id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php wc_product_class(); ?>>

    <?php
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_before_single_product_summary.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_images - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
    ?>

    <div class="summary entry-summary">
        <?php
            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_single_product_summary.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_after_single_product_summary.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
    ?>
</div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the complete code with comments:

```
// get current url
global $wp;
$current_url = home_url( add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request ) );

// add action with variabile in url to share
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','my_social_btn');
function my_social_btn() {
  echo '<div class="my-custom-social">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$current_url.'" class="social fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url='.$current_url.'" class="social tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
</div>
'
}
```

Here the css:

```
.my-custom-social{
    display:flex;
    font-size:25px;
    float:none;
    margin-top:60px;
}

.my-custom-social i{
   margin-right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see this line `<?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>`

Meand that there is a template page here `/woocommerce/content-single-product.php`

You need to open that page, depend on your template you can find directly what you want or another inclusion like that.

---

### update

Try to use hook to do what you want, put this in your theme function.php:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','my_social_btn');
function my_social_btn() {
    echo '<a href="#" class="social fb">share on FB</a><a href="#" class="social tw">share on TW</a>';
}
```

Comment: I updated the question to show the code in content-single-product.php rather.. but I still don't have a clue what I need to put.. and where

Comment: Cool thanks! I'll try that! How do I edit them if I want to change the look with CSS?

Comment: just change the echo part: add a wrapper with a class `    echo '<div class="my-social-wrapper"><a href="#" class="social fb">share on FB</a><a href="#" class="social tw">share on TW</a></div>';
`

Comment: I added it to functions.php but it doesn't work. I just added this - // add social media buttons to products
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','my_social_btn');
function my_social_btn() {
    echo '<a href="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/FacebookIcon.png" class="social fb"></a><a href="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/TwitterIcon.png" class="social tw"></a>';
}

Comment: pay attention you have empty href <a href="ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/…" class="social tw"></a> try to put some text inside <a> tag to see if it works

Comment: Here's the link btw - https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/product/charming-soft-pink-roses/

Comment: let me see I post you another answer, if my current answer help you don't forget to upvode it

Comment: Okay so now I have an icon.. which is great.. so you said "just change the echo part: add a wrapper with a class ` echo '" to change the look.. what do I need to say to make it smaller and move it underneath? Can I use CSS as it'll be easier?

Comment: Done, see new answer

Comment: Oh that's perfect.. thanks so much! It works perfectly..... my only question is... how come it doesn't show up on the phone??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197690/discussion-between-michelle-and-red).

Comment: Hi I have a quick question please.. I copied your code exactly but it doesn't share properly.. just opens a page with a share button and the URL but doesn't do anything or allow you to write a comment etc? Do you know why? Thanks